# .htaccess encoding already encoded URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https, apache2

I have the following .htaccess entry:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [L]
```

When linking to `http://...../?f=83|71|42` (which is URL-encoded by the browser to `http://...../?f=83%7C71%7C42`), it redirects to `https://...../?f=83%257C71%257C42`, encoding the `%` of `%7C` to `%25`, thus leading to the sequence `%257C`.

Is there any .htaccess syntax to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `NE` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [L,NE]
```